# Java BorderLayout stretch east

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

Is it possible to make the east (or west) side of a BorderLayout to spread over the entire panel (include north/south)?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove West and East from this panel and create a new "parent" panel:

```
JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
newPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

newPanel.add(westernPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
newPanel.add(yourOldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
newPanel.add(eastenPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 2):

not possible with single `JPanel` layed by `BorderLayout`

1) by using two `JPanels`, where `NORTH`, `WEST`, `CENTER` and `SOUTH` areas could be placed to the `1st JPanel` (`frame.add(1stPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)`) and plain `2nd JPanel` to the `frame.add(2ndPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)`,

2) you can use `BoxLayout` for area in the `EAST` from Container

3) little bit complicated could be use `GridBagLayout` or `MigLayout` (in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you could have a border layout with no "east" nested within a layout that has your current East in the correct position...  Make sense?

TL;DR:
No.